# Big O Notation logarithms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm having trouble with these two Big O notation proofs

> (b) $(n + \log_2 n)^5 = \Theta(n^5).$
>
> (b) $(\log_2 n)^5 = O(\log_2 n^5).$

For the first one, I'm having trouble finding a $c$ value to make $f(n) \le cg(n)$, can $c$ be any number?

For the second one, I think that it is false, as $f(n)$ will always be bigger than $g(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, notice that

$$\frac{(n + \log_2 n)^5}{n} = \left(1 + \frac{\log_2 n}{n}\right)^5$$

It is necessary to show that this fraction is bounded above and below. The lower bound is easy, since the term in parentheses is at least $1$. The upper bound can be done with the knowledge that $\log_2 n = O(n)$.

---

For the second one your result is correct but your argument is not. After all, $2n = O(n)$ even though $2n$ is always larger than $n$. The inequality must hold up to a constant, only. To argue correctly, notice that
$$\log_2(n^5) = 5 \log_2(n)$$
Now if you know how to show that $x^5 \ne O(x)$, you'll be off to a pretty good start.

Comment: You can be more precise and use $\log(n) = O(n^c)$ or, better, $o(n^c)$ for any $c > 0$.

Comment: @martycohen Indeed. One can also show that $\log x / x$ is maximized at $x = e$, so there's an explicit bound of $(1 + 1/e)^5 \approx 4.79$.

Comment: @T.Bongers What do you mean by the lower bound and upper bounds?

Comment: I mean something larger than the given quantity (which is fixed), and something larger than the given quantity (also fixed0.